# Call to a member function getLogoImageAttribute() on null error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, nginx

I am installing laravel app on a system running on LEMP stack. There arises an error following the installation of the laravel app and deploying all its files on the local nginx service. The source of the error the code below.

```js
/home/abdikani/laravel/hrm-3.1.6/script/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php
     * @param  array   $__data
     * @return string
     */
    protected function evaluatePath($__path, $__data)
    {
        $obLevel = ob_get_level();
 
        ob_start();
 
        extract($__data, EXTR_SKIP);
 
        // We'll evaluate the contents of the view inside a try/catch block so we can
        // flush out any stray output that might get out before an error occurs or
        // an exception is thrown. This prevents any partial views from leaking.
        try {
            include $__path;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->handleViewException($e, $obLevel);
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            $this->handleViewException(new FatalThrowableError($e), $obLevel);
        }
 
        return ltrim(ob_get_clean());
    }
 
    /**
     * Handle a view exception.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @param  int  $obLevel
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    protected function handleViewException(Exception $e, $obLevel)
    {
        while (ob_get_level() > $obLevel) {
            ob_end_clean();
        }
 
Arguments
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError {#424 ▶}
1
```

and attached is the error page. I would appreciate if somebody is able to tell me the what is wrong with the code. I tried my best and could not resolve it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvS9O.png)

This is the code where I call getLogoImageAttribute()

```js
 <body>
<!--=== Content Part ===-->    
<div class="container">
    <!--Reg Block-->
    {!!  Form::open(array('id'=>'login-form'))  !!}
    <div class="reg-block">
        <div class="reg-block-header">
            <h2><img src="{{$setting->getLogoImageAttribute()}}" width="117px" /></h2>
            <h3 class="text-center">Employee Panel</h3>
        </div>

        <div id="alert"></div>

        <div class="form-group rem margin-bottom-20">
            <div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"
                           placeholder="{{ trans('core.email') }}" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group rem margin-bottom-20">
            <div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"
                           placeholder="{{ trans('core.password') }}"
                           required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <label style="font-weight: normal;" class="margin-bottom-20 rem">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Always stay signed in
        </label>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <button type="submit" class="btn-u btn-block input-group" id="submitbutton"
                        onclick="login(); return false;">{{trans('core.btnLogin')}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End Reg Block-->
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div><!--/container-->
```

Comment: Can you show us the code in `login.blade.php` where you're calling `getLogoImageAttribute()`?

Comment: I have added the code @rickdenhaan

Comment: So according to the error message, `$setting` is `null`. You'll need to trace where it came from so you can figure out why it isn't the object you expect it to be.